# SharePoint WebPart Custom Properties: Password Field as Property

Tags: web-part

I want to create text password property with masked input in my visual web part sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the normal method of creating custom property. And for the `textbox` you can choose `TextMode` as follows

```
txtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
```

Here is an example on how to implement this https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/sharepoint-webpart-custom-properties-password-field-as-property/